# regex that only accepts numbers 2 and up

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that only allows the user to input numbers with a value of 2 or more (0 and 1 are not allowed)...

I have been trying to pull this off for quite a while with no success yet...
I have tried this one for example:

```
[2-9]|([1-9][0-9]+)
```

Either you take a single number from 2 to 9, or you input any number different from 0 AND at least another number...
that way there's no way the user can input either 0 or 1...

I don't know if there's a syntax error there or what should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want to use `Regex` for this task? Even then what happened when you tried it? It seems ok to me.

Comment: I need to do this for a sale registration...
when you decide to make payments in several periods, it's pretty obvious that it is not going to be one period... Let's say.. I sell something and you're gonna pay for the item for 6 months every 2 weeks... so that means that it should be 12 periods.

that one, it only allowed to input 2-9, but never 10 and up

Comment: @RohitJain Great point. What's the saying? If you have a problem and say: "I know, I'll use regular expressions to solve it," now you have two problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you Int32.TryParse first and then test whether the value you get is in the range that you want.  Here's a rough idea:

```
int enteredValue;

if(Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out enteredValue))
{
    if(enteredValue >= 2 )
    {
       //....
    }
}
```

Regex isn't meant for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: shouldn't have `&& enteredValue <=9`. OP states 2 or more

Comment: Oh, nicely spotted.  Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can actually do that in RegEx, and if you can do that you'd have a really complex looking RegEx string. But why use RegEx at all? You can simply check to see if the value is numeric and and larger than 1. On the client you can use JavaScript, then on the server double check again. Here's a JavaScript function to do this. You can use this in a CustomValidator if you so wish:

```
function CheckTwoOrLarger(x)
{
    result = false;

    if ( isFinite(x)         //Check if number
         && parseInt(x) >= 2 //Check if 2 or larger
         ) result = true;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: function checkGT2(x){ try { if( (1*x) > 2){ return true } } catch(e){}; return false; }

Comment: I prefer 1*x to parseInt.  Also works with floats but can be written 1.0*x to belabor the floating point.